# Can't get data from a json object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to console.log the "name" of the object. Everytime i try this it returns "undefined". How can i solve this?

```
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/quiz/code', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: code
        })
    }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            data = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log("data: " + data);
            console.log("name: " + data.name);
        })
```

This is the output of my first console.log:

```
data: [{"_id":"5cab356c8b35014074855ada","name":"fsgsdfgd","vragen":{"vragen":[{"question":"Hoe wordt een middagdutje zoals dit bijvoorbeeld in Spanje wordt gehouden genoemd?","answer":"Een siësta","category":"Algemeen"},{"question":"Hoe wordt een middagdutje zoals dit bijvoorbeeld in Spanje wordt gehouden genoemd?","answer":"Een siësta","category":"Algemeen"}]}}]
```

This is the output of my second console.log:

```
name: undefined
```

Comment: `data` is an `Array` of objects. You need to select the object in the array (by index) before you try to access the object's `name` property, i.e `console.log(data[0].name)`. Also remove `data = JSON.stringify(data);`. That just turns the Array into a String which is useless for your purposes.

Comment: If it's certain that the array will always have one element in, `data[0].name` can give you what you want

Comment: Try doing `data[0].name`

Comment: Why are you serializing your `data` ?

Comment: remove `data = JSON.stringify(data);` it converts data which is array to string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `stringify()` on the response data and then you treat it as an object. That cannot work. Just remove the `data = JSON.stringify(data);` as you already have valid JSON (in the form of an array). You can simply loop over the objects in the array and get each object's name:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:9000/quiz/code', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: code
    })
}).then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log("data: ", data);
        data.forEach(function(obj)  {
            console.log("name: " + obj.name);
        });
        console.log("name: " + data[0].name);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed the JSON.stringify(data) and added data[0].name to my console.log. This solved the problem. My new code looks like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:9000/quiz/code', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: code
        })
    }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            data = data;
            console.log("name: " + data[0].name);
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the stringify and use data[0].name

```js
data = [{"_id":"5cab356c8b35014074855ada","name":"fsgsdfgd","vragen":{"vragen":[{"question":"Hoe wordt een middagdutje zoals dit bijvoorbeeld in Spanje wordt gehouden genoemd?","answer":"Een siësta","category":"Algemeen"},{"question":"Hoe wordt een middagdutje zoals dit bijvoorbeeld in Spanje wordt gehouden genoemd?","answer":"Een siësta","category":"Algemeen"}]}}]

console.log(data[0].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//try like this
success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      show_edit_form();
      $('#txt_order_id').val(result[0].rec_id);
      $('#txt_first_name').val(result[0].fname);
      $('#txt_last_name').val(result[0].lname);
 },
```

Answer (score -2):

data: [{" is array

You should access to the array element before you get property by
 name:

Example access by index:

```
console.log("name: " + data[0].name);
```